# Disable input field, if some condition in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually i'm making a check out system for my collage project, which has 7 person and each person will work 8 hours and we have total 56 hours, so system will allow only 56 hours and if someone want extra time(total 3 shift in day),so the total time will deduct in next shift as per work and if total time will 0 the all input field will disable( ng-disable), i want to make this through Angular but facing some syntax problem my Code is

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    var total = 56,
    var checklist = [vm.spvc1,vm.spvc2,vm.spvc3,vm.spvc4,vm.spvc5,vm.spvc6,vm.spvc7];
    vm.check = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=checklist.length; i++){    
     if(checklist[i]!==""){
       var totalcheck = total-8;
     }
     return totalcheck;
    }
   console.log(totalcheck);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as main">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc3">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc4">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc5">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.spvc7">
    </div>
```

I'm newbie in Angular,and confuse how to use ng-disable, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

first you have to add ng-disabled to your inputs

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as main">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc1">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc2">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc3">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc4">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc5">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc6">
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc7">
</div>
```

in your controller after doing calculations for total time check if it is zero and set disableAll accordingly.

```
if(totaltime == 0){
    $scope.disableAll = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , so that mean i have to use ng-disable in every input and also could you please give me a answer  jsfield of better understanding because it show some syntax error , Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the error you get. That way I can help further.

Comment: Unexpected token var  and: [$injector:modulerr]

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <input type="text" ng-disabled=" workhour > 56 ?true:false" ng-model="main.spvc1">
means if work hour is greaterthen 56 then disable

replace the work hr with your object
```

Comment: Thank you of your response, But input is not hour its token no. of person that's why i use:                                                                   if(checklist[i]!=="")

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as main">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc1">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc2">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc3">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc4">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc5">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc6">
  <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-model="main.spvc7">
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    var total = 56;
    var checklist = [vm.spvc1,vm.spvc2,vm.spvc3,vm.spvc4,vm.spvc5,vm.spvc6,vm.spvc7];
    vm.check = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<=checklist.length(); i++){    
      if(checklist[i]!==""){
        var total = total-8;
      }
    }
    if(total === 0){
      $scope.disableAll = true;
    }
    return total;
   }
   console.log(total);
});
```

Comment: I hope it will help you. You missed } after for loop.

Comment: Check this JS Bin link. 
https://jsbin.com/yumuturowi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for your response, but suppose i fix the total value 48, so according to login last one should be disable but its not getting disable ...

Comment: and also as i checked console total its getting -8

Comment: I didn't get after login concept?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's work fine but when total value is 0 ,all field is getting disable i doesn't want previous field disable only further field disable,and also i have extra input field for Overtime(In Next Shift) and a person want 4 hr extra(which is also related to total) ,so the last one token no. should be disable and also previous input token should be editable ................i'm getting stuck in this logic, please help me out, thanks in advance –